# Formula parse error on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In my sheet in column H3 and all that follow below I want it to display "85.00" as long as column A is not blank, so this is what I put:

=H3:H IF(A3 <>"", "85.00","")

But doing that I get a "formula parse error".
It works fine if I don't include the "H3:H" after the = but i want this to be applied to all the cells below starting at H3.

I have a formula is column D that works just fine I don't know why this one which is simpler gives an error.

Anyone know what's happening here? Here is the sheet I'm working on:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PwtYQvCw2T6S0fKS7pAvctIQdB9Dd0q1xe0_ED4GAmk/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: I find it strange because that is exactly what I did for column D and works perfectly, the formula applied indefinitely all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use IF like that. It's a syntax error.

H3:

```
 = ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<>"", "85.00",""))
```

This will fill all the way down from H3 to H.